# react native scrollview scroll position

Tags: react-native

I'm making a chat app like Discord. But there was a problem.

First, the source is:

```
<SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
    <View style={{padding: 15, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
        <Text>HEADER</Text>
    </View>

    <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', backgroundColor: '#111111'}}>
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="position" style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'center'}} keyboardVerticalOffset={90} enabled>
                <ScrollView>
                    <View style={{height: 100}}><Text style={{color: 'white'}}>1</Text></View>
                    <View style={{height: 100}}><Text style={{color: 'white'}}>2</Text></View>
                    <View style={{height: 100}}><Text style={{color: 'white'}}>3</Text></View>
                    <View style={{height: 100}}><Text style={{color: 'white'}}>4</Text></View>
                    <View style={{height: 100}}><Text style={{color: 'white'}}>5</Text></View>
                    <View style={{height: 100}}><Text style={{color: 'white'}}>6</Text></View>
                    <View style={{height: 100}}><Text style={{color: 'white'}}>7</Text></View>
                    <View style={{height: 100}}><Text style={{color: 'white'}}>8</Text></View>
                    <View style={{height: 100}}><Text style={{color: 'white'}}>9</Text></View>
                    <View style={{height: 100}}><Text style={{color: 'white'}}>10</Text></View>
                    <View style={{height: 100}}><Text style={{color: 'white'}}>11</Text></View>
                    <View style={{height: 100}}><Text style={{color: 'white'}}>12</Text></View>
                    <View style={{height: 100}}><Text style={{color: 'white'}}>13</Text></View>
                    <View style={{height: 100}}><Text style={{color: 'white'}}>14</Text></View>
                    <View style={{height: 100}}><Text style={{color: 'white'}}>15</Text></View>
                    <View style={{height: 100}}><Text style={{color: 'white'}}>16</Text></View>
                    <View style={{height: 100}}><Text style={{color: 'white'}}>17</Text></View>
                    <View style={{height: 100}}><Text style={{color: 'white'}}>18</Text></View>
                    <View style={{height: 100}}><Text style={{color: 'white'}}>19</Text></View>
                    <View style={{height: 100}}><Text style={{color: 'white'}}>1</Text></View>
                    <View style={{height: 100}}><Text style={{color: 'white'}}>1</Text></View>
                    <View style={{height: 100}}><Text style={{color: 'white'}}>1</Text></View>
                    <View style={{height: 100}}><Text style={{color: 'white'}}>1</Text></View>
                </ScrollView>

                <View style={styles.test}>
                    <TextInput style={{
                        backgroundColor: '#2E2E2E',
                        width: '100%',
                        borderRadius: 18,
                        height: 36,
                        paddingLeft: 10,
                        paddingRight: 10,
                        color: '#FFFFFF'
                    }} />
                </View>
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        </View>
    </View>
</SafeAreaView>
```

The result is as below.

[image]

On the surface, there are no problems.

However, when the keyboard is raised, the content area invades the header as follows.

[image]

Another problem is that scrolling also invades the header area.

[image]

If you give the behavior part to the KeyboardAvoidingView tag as padding, the scrolling does not shift and works normally.

However, if you input with padding, the keyboard does not push the content part up when the keyboard comes up.

I tried various methods but still I failed.

please someone help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a `FlatList` combined with a `KeyboardAvoidingView`. The header must be placed differently and I've cleaned up the code a little bit. Notice that my `useEffect` is only triggered once in order to fill the test data. I use TypeScript as well, so you might remove typing.

The main "trick" for the `KeyboardAvoidingView` is the property `behavior` which differs between iOS and Android.

Consider this codesnippet.

```js
behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
```

And here is a full working version.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react"
import { FlatList, KeyboardAvoidingView, Text, TextInput, View } from "react-native"

type Message = {
  id?: number
  message?: string
  date?: Date
}

export const Test = () => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState<Message[]>()
  const flatListRef = useRef<FlatList>(null)

  // only for test
  useEffect(() => {
    setMessages([
      { id: 1 },
      { id: 2 },
      { id: 3 },
      { id: 4 },
      { id: 5 },
      { id: 6 },
      { id: 7 },
      { id: 8 },
      { id: 9 },
      { id: 10 },
      { id: 11 },
      { id: 12 },
    ])
  }, [])

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "red", paddingTop: 30 }}>
      <View style={{ padding: 15, justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <Text>HEADER</Text>
      </View>
      <KeyboardAvoidingView
        behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
        style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#111111" }}>
        <FlatList
          data={messages}
          ref={flatListRef}
          onContentSizeChange={() => flatListRef.current.scrollToEnd({ animated: true })}
          onLayout={() => flatListRef.current.scrollToEnd({ animated: true })}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
          renderItem={({ item }) => <Text style={{ color: "white", flex: 1, paddingVertical: 20 }}>{item.id}</Text>}
        />
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: "black", flex: 1, marginBottom: 40 }}>
          <TextInput
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "#2E2E2E",
              width: "100%",
              borderRadius: 18,
              height: 36,
              paddingLeft: 10,
              paddingRight: 10,
              color: "#FFFFFF",
            }}
          />
        </View>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    </View>
  )
}
```

The above results in the correct behavior. However, I've only tested this on iOS. Android might behave differently.

Using `FlatList` is not a necessity but usually advised.

Here is a screeshot.

[image]

**Edit:** For automatically scrolling the flatlist content if the keyboard is opened, add the following props to the flatlist.

```js
ref={flatListRef}
onContentSizeChange={() => flatListRef.current.scrollToEnd({animated: true })}
onLayout={() => flatListRef.current.scrollToEnd({ animated: true })}
```

The `flatListRef` is a ref which can be set as follows.

```js
const flatListRef = useRef<FlatList>(null)
```

I have updated the full working example above.

Comment: thanks bro,

But as the keyboard comes up, it doesn't push the content up.

Comment: So the textinput is pushed up but you want the content of the list also pushed up?

Comment: @이승준 Please consider my updated answer.

Comment: You are very welcome!